# Laravel Spatie/Permission filter for multi-tenant

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I have 3 main models:

- Users
- Branches
- Objects

Every user will belong to a `Branch` and a `Branch` will have many `Users`.

`Objects` will belong to `Users` and to `Branch` as well, so `Objects` has a `user_id` as well as a `branch_id` like so:

```
//Objects DB table tructure
[
 "id",
 "name",
 "branch_id",
 "user_id",
 "created_at",
 "updated_at",
]
```

So this is my current setup:

**Models/Branch.php**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

**Models/Users.php**

```
public function branch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Branch::class);
}
```

**Models/Objects.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now I've setup [Spatie/Permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) with following `Roles`:

- `Super-Admin`: will see every `Objects` of every `Branch`
- `Admin`: will see every `Objects` of its own `Branch` and not from other `Branches`
- `User`: will see every `Objects` he created an not any other in his own `Branch` or outside of it

My point now is to list all `Objects` based off of the User permission.
My first idea is to build relations based on models, but I'm not sure this is a good idea and practice, this is the code:

```
public function objects(){

    $user = auth()->user();

    if ($user->hasRole("Super-Admin")) {
        return Object::query();
    }

    if ($user->hasRole("Admin")) {
        return Object::where('branch_id', '=', $user->branch()->pluck('id'));
    }

    return $this->hasMany(Object::class);

}
```

Does this make sense at all? Should I use any other more appropriate Laravel functionalities/API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aproach you are using does make sense, the only thing that concerns me is using the authenticated user inside a function on the model.

That could cause same conflicts, for example if a super-admin wants to see the objects of a normal user then this function is no good for you because all the time you are going to retrieve the objects of the super-admin.

i would use your function as follows

```
public function objects(){

   if ($this->hasRole("Super-Admin")) {
       return Object::query();
   }

   if ($this->hasRole("Admin")) {
       return Object::where('branch_id', '=', $this->branch()->pluck('id'));
   }

   return $this->hasMany(Object::class);
}
```

And then on the Controllers when using

```
$user->objects();
```

you are retrieving the objects of the user object you have at the given time

Comment: That's super smart! Thanks!